# How to deploy Node.js app on Hostinger VPS

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, backend, hosting

I want to deploy my Node.js app to Hostinger VPS. I found some YouTube videos that show how to do this, but they are all very long and complex. Is there any simpler way to deploy Node.js app without having to go through such a complicated process?

If anyone knows of a simpler way to deploy Node.js apps to Hostinger VPS, I would appreciate the help. Thanks!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.